# Как удалить активный Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно удалить действующий фрэйм в Tkinter. То есть у меня окно состоит из двух Frame, первый - с кнопками, второй - картинка. Мне надо чтобы шло определение активного(размещённого в окне) Frame, удаление его и открытие нового. На данный момень меняются оба Frame и очень много команд для кнопок, это не очень удобно. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно записать в переменную (или поле объекта) какой из фреймов активный, при переключении для старого активного фрейма сделать `pack_forget`, для нового активного сделать `pack` (или `grid_forget`/`grid`, если фреймы размещены с помощью `grid`).

Пример (циклическое переключение между тремя фреймами):

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.frames = []

        self.add_frame(text="Frame 1")
        self.add_frame(text="Frame 2")
        self.add_frame(text="Frame 3")

        tk.Button(self, text="Next frame", command=self.next_frame).pack()

        self.active_frame = 0
        self.frames[self.active_frame].pack()

    def add_frame(self, text):
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        tk.Label(frame, text=text).pack()
        self.frames.append(frame)

    def next_frame(self):
        self.frames[self.active_frame].pack_forget()
        self.active_frame = (self.active_frame + 1) % len(self.frames)
        self.frames[self.active_frame].pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```